# Integer polynomials such that $f(z) = 0, |z| = 1$

Tags: polynomials, roots, circles, roots-of-unity

Let $f(z)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients of degree $n$.
Also $f(z)$ is irreducible over the integers, and it is not a cyclotomic polynomial.

Let $v$ be a given nonreal complex number.

Consider solving $f(z)=0$ on the complex plane.

For a given $v$ let $z_0$ be the nearest number to it such that

$$f(z_0) = 0$$

Now for what integer polynomials $f(z)$ do we have some $v$ such that

$$f(z_0)=0, |z_0| = 1 $$

??

It might be useful to write

$$z_0^m = \cos(m w) + \sin(m w) i$$

( de moivre formula )

and then setting

$$f(  \cos(w) + \sin(w) i ) = 0 $$

This way we solve for a real $w$ if it exists.

By using chebychev polynomials we can get a system of 2 polynomial equations for the real and imag part.

Maybe that helps.

Minimum polynomial probably related too.

How to classify the solutions $f(z)$ ??

Comment: "For a given $v$ let $z_0$ be the nearest number to it such that $f(z_0) = 0$" Umm, how does $z_0$ depend on $v$?

Comment: What do you want as a classification? we could say they're precisely the polynomials that are multiples of the minimal polynomial of $z$ for some algebraic $z$ with $|z|=1$. What is the classification for?

Comment: @5xum say z_0 = i and v was i + 0.01. v is just there to distinguish the roots.

Comment: @ZoeAllen like a parametric description or formula in terms of the coefficients ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Lets say $f(z)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Then the zero's of $f(z)$ come in two kinds.

First the real ones.

Secondly pairs of complex conjugates.

Those complex conjugate pairs have ( for every pair ) a minimum polynomial of degree 2.

More precisely if the complex conjugate pairs are on the unit circle , then the minimum polynomial is of the form

$$ z^2 + 2 \cos(\theta) + 1$$

where $\theta$ is the argument of one the zero's.

This implies the minimum polynomial is of the form

$$ z^2 + 2 v + 1$$

where $v$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$.

This implies that $f(z)$ is irreducible ( so $+1$ or $-1$ is not a zero ) then
we have the factorization over the reals of $f(z)$ :

$$f(z) = (z^2 + 2 v + 1)^n g(z)$$

for some integer $n$ and $v$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$ and a polynomial $g(z)$ with real coefficients.

We can reduce this by putting $n$ equal to $1$.

So

$$f(z) = (z^2 + 2 v + 1) h(z)$$

So basicly we are looking for a $v$ such that $v$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$ and

$$ f(z) = 0 \mod (z^2 + 2 v + 1) $$

This is just polynomial division and checking for a remainder, but with a parameter.